# Dynamic added controls in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I create Two `textboxes` dynamically and append it into table Row.
    Now I need to validate the `Textboxes` if empty or It having values.If it empty means need to highlight the textboxes.
    If I press `ValidateControls button` ,that particular row `textboxes` need to highlighted If it is `Empty`.
    If i press `VAlidateAllControls` means need to highlight all `textboxes` in a table if it is Empty.

How To do this? Please refer the Fiddle Link

```
     <script>
         $(document).ready(function () {
             $("#inputId").click(function () {

                 var table = $('table#mytable');
                 var row = "<tr><td> <input name='Name' id='Name' type='text' />* </td>" +
                                    "<td> <input name='Email' id='Email' type='text' /> </td>" +
                                    "<td> <input id='btnAdd' type='button' value='ValidateControls' /> "+
                                 "</tr>";
                 var col = $('<td style="width:100px;" align="left"></td>');
                 table.append(row);
             });
         });
    </script>

BODY

<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <input type="button" id="inputId" value="ADD Controls"/>
        <input type="button" id="ValidateAll" value="Validate All Controls"/>
        <table id="mytable"></table>
    </form>
```

[Live Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6aBEf/1/)

Comment: @SridharR just now I added fiddle link.Please review it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$('#mytable').on('click', '#btnAdd', function () {
      $(this).parents('tr').find('input:text').each(function () {
          if ($(this).val() == '') $(this).css('border', '1px solid red')
          else $(this).css('border', '1px solid grey')
      });
  });
  $('#form1').on('click', '#ValidateAll', function () {
      $('#mytable').find('input:text').each(function () {
          if ($(this).val() == '') $(this).css('border', '1px solid red')
          else $(this).css('border', '1px solid grey')
      });
  });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6aBEf/3/)